# Хранение настроек доступа в переменных окружения

Tags: django, .env, environment-variables

Везде пишут, что все настройки (`API KEY, TOKEN, SQL LOGIN/PASS...`) в приложениях `Django` лучше всего хранить в переменных окружения, загружать их в репозиторий - не очень хорошая практика. Пообщался со знакомым, который работает мидлом (правда он C#, но, думаю особо разницы нет) - он сказал, что у них все это хранится просто в конфигурационном файле, который загружается в приватный гит и все оттуда берут эти доступы без проблем, и так как гит приватный внутри предприятия, то никто другой не может посмотреть этот файл, поэтому утечки не возникает. Почему тогда рекомендуют использовать переменные окружения, а не так?

Comment: Если миддл имеет возможность прочитать пароли — это уже автоматически означает, что всё организовано очень плохо. Доступа к паролям не должно быть ни у кого, кроме небольшого числа привилегированных сотрудников/админов

Comment: @andreymal у него скорее всего доступ к какому-нибудь конфиг файлу на тестовом стенде, не вижу в этом никакой проблемы т.к на бою будут 100% совсем другие пароли

Comment: Ну а применительно к тестовому стенду этот вопрос не имеет смысла, тестовый стенд всё равно не жалко

Comment: В c# есть большой набор функций, как организовать хранение от appsetting.json до azure keyVault. Поэтому сравнение не состоятельно. В моей голове для джанго использовать только переменные окружения

Comment: @Dmitry теоретически «привилегированные сотрудники/админы» могут для джанго использовать свой собственный settings.py, который никому не будут показывать

Comment: Спасибо за ответы